# Export Category IDs

Tags: magento-1.8, category, export

Used this script for ages but now need the actual category Ids to be exported.

```
    public function getAttributes() {
    $data = array();
    $data[] = array (‘field’ => ‘id’, ‘label’ => ‘ID’,’required’ => ‘yes’);
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'name', 'label' => 'Name','required' => 'yes');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'path', 'label' => 'Path', 'function' => 'getFullPath','required' => 'yes' );
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'position', 'label' => 'Position');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'is_active', 'label' => 'Is Active', 'function' => 'getYesNo');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'url_key', 'label' => 'Url Key');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'description', 'label' => 'Description');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'image', 'label' => 'Image');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'meta_title', 'label' => 'Page Title');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'meta_keywords', 'label' => 'Meta Keywords');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'meta_description', 'label' => 'Meta Description');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'include_in_menu', 'label' => 'Include In Menu', 'function' => 'getYesNo');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'display_mode', 'label' => 'Display Mode', 'function' => 'getDisplayMode');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'landing_page', 'label' => 'CMS Block', 'function' => 'getStaticBlock');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'is_anchor', 'label' => 'Is Anchor', 'function' => 'getYesNo');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'available_sort_by', 'label' => 'Availabe Sort By', 'function' => 'getProductSortBy');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'default_sort_by', 'label' => 'Default Sort By', 'function' => 'getProductSortBy');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'page_layout', 'label' => 'Page Layout', 'function' => 'getPageLayout');
    $data[] = array ('field' => 'custom_layout_update', 'label' => 'Custom Layout Update');
    return $data;
}}
```

this being the new line added

```
$data[] = array (‘field’ => ‘id’, ‘label’ => ‘ID’,’required’ => ‘yes’);
```

but it doesnt export the category id numbers.

Comment: replace `id` with `entity_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple script to export categories Ids in CSV

```
<?php
 define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
 $mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
 require_once $mageFilename;
 Mage::app();
 $allCategories = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/category' );
 $categoryTree = $allCategories->getTreeModel();
 $categoryTree->load();
 $categoryIds = $categoryTree->getCollection()->getAllIds(); 

 if ($categoryIds) {
     $outputFile = "var/importexport/categories-and-ids.csv";
     $write = fopen($outputFile, 'w');

 foreach ( $categoryIds as $categoryId ) {
         $data = array($allCategories->load($categoryId)->getName(), $categoryId);
         fputcsv($write, $data);
     }
 }

 fclose($write);
 ?>
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Hi

Just found that it works perfectly. Thanks

Was looking at now activating the categories en mass. Starting a new post

Comment: would love to but reputation is too low

Answer (score 2):

You have issue in your syntax, replace "‘" to "'" and **id with entity_id** so please replace your first line with following

```
$data[] = array ('field' => 'entity_id', 'label' => 'ID','required' => 'yes');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write this one pretty easily. Create a php file called something like `export.php`.

```
<?php
     require("app/Mage.php");  // load the main Mage file Mage::app();   // not run() because you just want to load Magento, not run it.

     //load all of the active categories in the system and include all attributes 
        $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
          ->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
          ->addIsActiveFilter();

         $export_file = "var/export/categories.csv"; // assumes that you're running from the web root. var/ is typically writable  $export = fopen($export_file, 'w') or die("Permissions error."); // open the file for writing.  if you see the error then check the folder permissions.

         $output = "";

         $output = "id,name\r\n"; // column names. end with a newline.  fwrite($export, $output); // write the file header with the column names


         foreach ($categories as $category) {
             $output = ""; // re-initialize $output on each iteration
             $output .= $category->getId().','; // no quote - integer
             $output .= '"'.$category->getName().'",'; // quotes - string
             // add any other fields you want here 
             $output .= "\r\n"; // add end of line
             fwrite($export, $output); // write to the file handle "$export" with the string "$output".  }

         fclose($export); // close the file handle.

    ?>
```

Comment: For your effort. +1